# Excel cube: create new measure as sum of existing measures

Tags: dax, powerpivot

I have no idea what to put in the *formula* box, and the help (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-measure-in-power-pivot-d3cc1495-b4e5-48e7-ba98-163022a71198?ns=excel&version=90&syslcid=1033&uilcid=1033&appver=zxl900&helpid=149601&ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us) says simple *enter a formula*.

Is there any documentation?

[image]

Neither

```
=SUM(dsv_FactIncome[ClientValue], dsv_FactIncome[PartnerValue])
```

nor

```
=SUMX(dsv_FactIncome[ClientValue], dsv_FactIncome[PartnerValue])
```

are acceptable to it, either.

Comment: Was your problem solved?

Answer (score 0):

This is DAX and your syntax is incorrect. Try

=SUM(dsv_FactIncome[ClientValue]) + SUM(dsv_FactIncome[PartnerValue])